# Pytorch how to get the gradient of loss function twice

Tags: tensorflow, pytorch

Here is what I'm trying to implement:

We calculate loss based on `F(X)`, as usual. But we also define "adversarial loss" which is a loss based on `F(X + e)`. `e` is defined as `dF(X)/dX` multiplied by some constant. Both loss and adversarial loss are backpropagated for the total loss.

In tensorflow, this part (getting `dF(X)/dX`) can be coded like below:

```
  grad, = tf.gradients( loss, X )
  grad = tf.stop_gradient(grad)
  e = constant * grad
```

Below is my pytorch code:

```
class DocReaderModel(object):
    def __init__(self, embedding=None, state_dict=None):
        self.train_loss = AverageMeter()
        self.embedding = embedding
        self.network = DNetwork(opt, embedding)
        self.optimizer = optim.SGD(parameters)

    def adversarial_loss(self, batch, loss, embedding, y):
        self.optimizer.zero_grad()
        loss.backward(retain_graph=True)
        grad = embedding.grad
        grad.detach_()

        perturb = F.normalize(grad, p=2)* 0.5
        self.optimizer.zero_grad()
        adv_embedding = embedding + perturb
        network_temp = DNetwork(self.opt, adv_embedding) # This is how to get F(X)
        network_temp.training = False
        network_temp.cuda()
        start, end, _ = network_temp(batch) # This is how to get F(X)
        del network_temp # I even deleted this instance.
        return F.cross_entropy(start, y[0]) + F.cross_entropy(end, y[1])

    def update(self, batch):
        self.network.train()
        start, end, pred = self.network(batch)
        loss = F.cross_entropy(start, y[0]) + F.cross_entropy(end, y[1])
        loss_adv = self.adversarial_loss(batch, loss, self.network.lexicon_encoder.embedding.weight, y) 
        loss_total = loss + loss_adv 

        self.optimizer.zero_grad()
        loss_total.backward()
        self.optimizer.step()
```

I have few questions:

1) I substituted tf.stop_gradient with grad.detach_(). Is this correct?

2) I was getting `"RuntimeError: Trying to backward through the graph a second time, but the buffers have already been freed. Specify retain_graph=True when calling backward the first time."` so I added `retain_graph=True` at the `loss.backward`. That specific error went away.
However now I'm getting a memory error after few epochs (`RuntimeError: cuda runtime error (2) : out of memory at /opt/conda/conda-bld/pytorch_1525909934016/work/aten/src/THC/generic/THCStorage.cu:58`
). I suspect I'm unnecessarily retaining graph.

Can someone let me know pytorch's best practice on this? Any hint / even short comment will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are trying to implement generative adversarial network (GAN), but from the code, I don't understand and can't follow to what you are trying to achieve as there are a few missing pieces for a GAN to works. I can see there's a discriminator network module, `DNetwork` but missing the generator network module.

If to guess, when you say 'loss function twice', I assumed you mean you have one loss function for the discriminator net and another for the generator net. If that's the case, let me share how I would implement a basic GAN model.

As an example, let's take a look at this [Wasserstein GAN Jupyter notebook](https://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/cedrickchee/wasserstein-gan/blob/master/wgan-pytorch.ipynb#Create-model)

I'll skip the less important bits and zoom into the important ones here:

1. First, import PyTorch libraries and set up

   ```
   # Set up batch size, image size, and size of noise vector:
   bs, sz, nz = 64, 64, 100 # nz is the size of the latent z vector for creating some random noise later
   ```
2. Build a discriminator module

   ```
   class DCGAN_D(nn.Module):
       def __init__(self):
           ... truncated, the usual neural nets stuffs, layers, etc ...
       def forward(self, input):
           ... truncated, the usual neural nets stuffs, layers, etc ...
   ```
3. Build a generator module

   ```
   class DCGAN_G(nn.Module):
       def __init__(self):
           ... truncated, the usual neural nets stuffs, layers, etc ...
       def forward(self, input):
           ... truncated, the usual neural nets stuffs, layers, etc ...
   ```
4. Put them all together

   ```
   netG = DCGAN_G().cuda()
   netD = DCGAN_D().cuda()
   ```
5. Optimizer needs to be told what variables to optimize. A module automatically keeps track of its variables.

   ```
   optimizerD = optim.RMSprop(netD.parameters(), lr = 1e-4)
   optimizerG = optim.RMSprop(netG.parameters(), lr = 1e-4)
   ```
6. One forward step and one backward step for Discriminator

   Here, the network can calculate gradient during the backward pass, depends on the input to this function. So, in my case, I have 3 type of losses; generator loss, dicriminator real image loss, dicriminator fake image loss. I can get gradient of loss function three times for 3 different net passes.

   ```
   def step_D(input, init_grad):
       # input can be from generator's generated image data or input image from dataset
       err = netD(input)
       err.backward(init_grad) # backward pass net to calculate gradient
       return err # loss
   ```
7. **Control trainable parameters** [IMPORTANT]

   Trainable parameters in the model are those that require gradients.

   ```
   def make_trainable(net, val):
       for p in net.parameters():
           p.requires_grad = val # note, i.e, this is later set to False below in netG update in the train loop.
   ```

   In TensorFlow, this part can be coded like below:

   `grad = tf.gradients(loss, X)
   grad = tf.stop_gradient(grad)`

   So, I think this will answer your first question, "I substituted tf.stop_gradient with grad.detach_(). Is this correct?"
8. Train loop

You can see here how's the 3 different loss functions are being called here.

```
    def train(niter, first=True):

        for epoch in range(niter):
            # Make iterable from PyTorch DataLoader
            data_iter = iter(dataloader)
            i = 0

            while i < n:
                ###########################
                # (1) Update D network
                ###########################
                make_trainable(netD, True)

                # train the discriminator d_iters times
                d_iters = 100

                j = 0

                while j < d_iters and i < n:
                    j += 1
                    i += 1

                    # clamp parameters to a cube
                    for p in netD.parameters():
                        p.data.clamp_(-0.01, 0.01)

                    data = next(data_iter)

                    ##### train with real #####
                    real_cpu, _ = data
                    real_cpu = real_cpu.cuda()
                    real = Variable( data[0].cuda() )
                    netD.zero_grad()

                    # Real image discriminator loss
                    errD_real = step_D(real, one)

                    ##### train with fake #####
                    fake = netG(create_noise(real.size()[0]))
                    input.data.resize_(real.size()).copy_(fake.data)

                    # Fake image discriminator loss
                    errD_fake = step_D(input, mone)

                    # Discriminator loss
                    errD = errD_real - errD_fake
                    optimizerD.step()

                ###########################
                # (2) Update G network
                ###########################
                make_trainable(netD, False)
                netG.zero_grad()

                # Generator loss
                errG = step_D(netG(create_noise(bs)), one)
                optimizerG.step()

                print('[%d/%d][%d/%d] Loss_D: %f Loss_G: %f Loss_D_real: %f Loss_D_fake %f'
                    % (epoch, niter, i, n,
                    errD.data[0], errG.data[0], errD_real.data[0], errD_fake.data[0]))
```

> "I was getting "RuntimeError: Trying to backward through the graph a second time..."

PyTorch has this behaviour; to reduce GPU memory usage, during the `.backward()` call, all the intermediary results (if you have like saved activations, etc.) are deleted when they are not needed anymore. Therefore, if you try to call `.backward()` again, the intermediary results don't exist and the backward pass cannot be performed (and you get the error you see).

It depends on what you are trying to do. You can call `.backward(retain_graph=True)` to make a backward pass that will not delete intermediary results, and so you will be able to call `.backward()` again. All but the last call to backward should have the `retain_graph=True` option.

> Can someone let me know pytorch's best practice on this

As you can see from the PyTorch code above and from the way things are being done in PyTorch which is trying to stay Pythonic, you can get a sense of PyTorch's best practice there.

Comment: Hi Cedrick, thanks for your answer! However, I'm not trying to implement GAN. I'm implementing Adversarial Training: https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/adversarial_text

Comment: OK. I am not familiar with Adversarial Training. I'm guessing GAN and Adversarial Training has some overlap in the 'adversarial' part. So, between the two, I think there should share many similar concepts and methods which I think I have explained and provided code examples. I don't think the differences between the two matters so much. More importantly, does it shed some light into your problem? Please let me know if you find this is not useful and how can I help to improved my answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to work with higher-order derivatives (i.e. a derivative of a derivative) take a look at the `create_graph` option of [`backward`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/autograd.html#torch.autograd.backward).

For example:

```
loss = get_loss()
loss.backward(create_graph=True)
loss_grad_penalty = loss + loss.grad
loss_grad_penalty.backward()
```